# How do I show a modal when the page loads

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to show a pop up modal on a html page **without** bootstrap. My code does not have any js, only CSS and HTML. To show it I am using CSS, but there is no display property. I have already tried jquery like this

```css
.popupmodal {
  display: block;
  line-height: 250%;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.popupmodal:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.popupmodal>div {
  height: auto;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 3% 2% 3% 2%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 1%;
}

.popup-modal-quest>div {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 1% auto;
  height: 60vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#quest-modal").show();
  });
</script>

<a href="#quest-modal" class="abrir-modal">You have a new quest. Click here to see.</a>


<div id="quest-modal" class="popupmodal popup-modal-quest">
  <div class="modal-quest">
    <img src="img/wooden-warning.png">
    <div class="btns-quest">
      <a href="#open-modal"><input type="button" value="Accept quest" class="btn-quest"></a>
      <a href="#go-back-page"><input type="button" value="Do not accept quest" class="btn-quest"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am new on jquery and js, so I am learning the best ways to solve these kinda problems. I would like to know if there is a good way to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the rule `opacity` was set to 0 by default:

```
.popupmodal {
    ...
    opacity: 0;
    ...
}
```

And the `show()` method **does not** affect this rule.

You need to set the `opacity` rule to 1, like this:

```
$("#quest-modal").css("opacity", "1");
```

```css
.popupmodal {
    display: block;
    line-height: 250%;
    font-size: 2.5vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.popupmodal:target {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.popupmodal > div {
    height: auto;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 3% 2% 3% 2%;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 1%;
}

.popup-modal-quest > div {
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 1% auto;
    height: 60vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#quest-modal").css("opacity", "1");
    });
</script>

<a href="#quest-modal" class="abrir-modal">You have a new quest. Click here to see.</a>

<div id="quest-modal" class="popupmodal popup-modal-quest">
    <div class="modal-quest">
        <img src="img/wooden-warning.png" />
        <div class="btns-quest">
            <a href="#open-modal"><input type="button" value="Accept quest" class="btn-quest" /></a>
            <a href="#go-back-page"><input type="button" value="Do not accept quest" class="btn-quest" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution looks interesting, but unfortunately it is not working.. The page loads and nothing happens...

Comment: I tried both of them, the .on and .ready.

Comment: @LisandraFerraz, What does the browser console show after launching the page? There are mistakes?

Comment: No, there are nothing

Comment: @LisandraFerraz, This is strange. Is your modal display: none; by default?

Comment: No, it is not. This modal is using two different classes to stylize them, so should I put display none in both?

Comment: Ok, I got it. I put it only in popupmodal class and it worked. Thank you a lot!!

Comment: @LisandraFerraz, I am glad to help. If you have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: Sure. I thought it had worked but I was wrong... Even with the property display none the modal does not appear.

Comment: @LisandraFerraz, Add complete code. Because it's hard to guess the problem without a code.

Comment: sorry, I guess I double clicked. Here is the codepen link. There are a few errors in its console, but these do not display in HTML page. https://codepen.io/lisandraf/pen/zYNybvP

Comment: @LisandraFerraz, I have given a new answer. Need to fix rule `opacity`. I wrote how to do it.

Comment: ok, It worked but now i can not interact with the input button.

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet of code you have is JavaScript not CSS, in order to make it work you have to include jQuery in your index.html. Something like this (you can change the version)

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

otherwise calling '$' without defining it will result in errors. If you're looking for a more complete solution, checkout jQuery UI's [Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default). They even have an example for how to use with source code.

Comment: I did this but it does not work as well... When I put JS first the page become empty, without any content.

Answer (score 0):

#quest-modal in the css

```
#quest-modal{
display: block;
}
```

This will set default to visible.

Answer (score 0):

Add a close button and fixed some of the styling.

```
.popupmodal {
  display: block;
  line-height: 250%;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This is an example!:

```js
function closing(){
 var element = document.getElementById("quest");
  element.classList.add("hide-modal-popup");
}
    function opening(){
        var elements = document.getElementById("quest");
  elements.classList.remove("hide-modal-popup");
    }
    function opening2(){
        var elements = document.getElementById("quest-2");
  elements.classList.remove("hide-modal-popup");
    }
function closing2(){
 var element = document.getElementById("quest-2");
  element.classList.add("hide-modal-popup");
}
closing2();
```

```css
.modal {
  display: block; /* Show by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}   
.hide-modal-popup{
  display: none !important;
}
button,input {
    cursor: pointer;
    }
.modal-quest {
  line-height: 250%;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  height: auto;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 3% 2% 3% 2%;
  border-radius: 1%;
}
.popup-modal-quest>div {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 1% auto;
  height: 60vh;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="opening();" class="abrir-modal">You have a new quest. Click here to see.</button>


<div id="quest" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-quest">
    <img src="img/wooden-warning.png">
    <div class="btns-quest">
      <button class="btn-quest" onclick="opening2();closing();">Accept quest</button>
         <button class="btn-quest" onclick="closing();">Do not accept quest</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="quest-2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-quest">
    <img src="img/wooden-warning.png">
    <div class="btns-quest">
    <h1>This is the second modal.</h1>
         <button class="btn-quest" onclick="closing2();">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey! I did it but I can not interact with the inputs anymore. The modal just appears and I can select the HTML items behind, but not the modal's. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Yes There is you can put a close button.

Comment: call opening to open popup like this `opening();`

Comment: call closing to close popup like this `closing();`

Comment: I have already done it without JS, only using HTML elements. My objective is show the modal quest when the page loads. There are two buttons inside it. Due to the opacity 1 from jquery/css I cannot interact with the buttons, so they do not work and it is impossible to click in. When I click in accept one, it is supposed to open another modal, but if I click in do not accept, it must close and return to the original page behind.